# edit Active Directory user information in Sharepoint 2010 site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory

I'm trying to edit some retrieved fields from the Active Directory within a Sharepoint 2010 site and submit the changes back to the Active Directory.

I tried one solution I found online but it doesn't work. What I did is:

-Synchronized user profiles
-changed "Property Mapping for Synchronization" to Export for the specific fields I want to edit
-gave Edit Personal User Information permission to system account user in the site and active directory synchronization account (just to make sure).

When I open any user's information on the site, the edit button is available but the fields can not be edited.

I mad sure the user have the permission but still not able to edit fields.

Is there any other way to edit those fields and send them back to Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hard coding permissions within SharePoint. I had a project once similar to that and ended up hard coding admin permission to active directory for it. Passing permissions back and forth between Active Directory and SharePoint can be interesting. Also make sure you are using the correct callback form field. Depending on how the active directory was set up they could be using something different for the field.. Example UserFirstName Or UserName.